# Setup AVAudioPlayer with swift 1.2?

Tags: swift, audio

When I tried to setup AVaudioPlayer last time, I used this code:

```
func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer  {
    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType:type)
    var url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    var error: NSError?
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
    return audioPlayer!
}

 var buttonBeep = AVAudioPlayer()

 buttonBeep = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("buttonPush", type:"m4a")
```

And it worked perfectly. Now with Swift 1.2 it seems that I can't do that.

I also tried this code:

```
var button : AVAudioPlayer?

in didMoveToView:

if let button = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("button", type:"m4a") {
        self.button = button
    }

func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer?  {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

    var error: NSError?
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
    return audioPlayer
}
```

It gives me an error on let url line - EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. I put my audio file in Supporting Files inside my project. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** that was my mistake. If you have the same problem — make sure you are adding sounds to a target of your app, not just in project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {

        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
        if (url == nil) {
            println("Could not find file: \(filename)")
            return
        }

        var error: NSError? = nil
        backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
        if backgroundMusicPlayer == nil {
            println("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        backgroundMusicPlayer.play()

}
```

Use it this way:

```
playBackgroundMusic("button.m4a")
```

Hope it helps.

It was working fine with 1.2 and I didn't test it right now because I have updated my Xcode and I suggest you to use latest version of Xcode which have swift version 2.0.

Comment: It tells me that it couldn't find the file. Is it ok to put audiofiles in Supporting Files folder or should I put it somewhere else? As I remember I used this folder earlier, but not sure. Also, how to play another sound with your code? I used to simply do `button.play()` or `bgMusic.play()` but as I understood I need to declare audio files differently with this code

Comment: I have added my audio files into supporting file folder and it is working fine.Make sure you are not mistaking with file name.

Comment: url line is the problem. It couldn't find the file!

Comment: Well, it's pretty much in my question and your answer. If I try your answer it shows me `could not find file button.m4a` and crashes if I tap on a button and it should perform sound. If I use code from my question it crashes immediately and tells me `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I double checked every name, tried to do this on another sound file, tried to replace file in the main directory.

Comment: You can see my code for that scene [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ccgofklffpitsmp/AAD4dy23rsNiq2cBikmVbgIia?dl=0)

Comment: Ok i will check that.